# How to know which user-agent is currently used in the scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, attributes

I would like to know how to access which user-agent is currently used.
For instance I want to `print()` in the terminal during the process: `the current user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1` or in the log file. How could I access to it with scrapy?

Version: Scrapy 1.5.2

Comment: How exactly are you making the request?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I hope it gonna answer your question. I set a user-agent list in the `settings.py` file as `USER_AGENT_LIST= [...]` and I precise still in `settings.py` the middlewares' function: `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES= {'chevaux_p_t.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,...}`. Then in `middlewares.py` file: `class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(settings.get('USER_AGENT_LIST'))
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)` in this [topic](https://gist.github.com/bcambel/4365185)

Comment: Can you post your script ? I have something similar but it is hard to see what you are doing. Pretty sure all you need is to add a print statement to your settings.py

Comment: @EdekiOkoh that seems stupid but I think the solution is actually in this [topic](https://gist.github.com/bcambel/4365185) with: `#log.msg('>>>> UA %s'%request.headers)`

Comment: That should work if you remove the comment in the  log.msg('>>>> UA %s'%request.headers) line. But you need to make sure you have logging on in your main file

Comment: @EdekiOkoh it works when I write `print("the current user-agent is:{}".format(request.headers[b'User-Agent']))` it gives `the current user-agent is:b'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.991'` as expected and if I want to in the log I do `logging.debug('the current user-agent is:{}'.format(request.headers[b'User-Agent']))`. It works. Thanks.

Comment: You should post it as the answer so others know also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user-agent is set like in this [solution](https://gist.github.com/bcambel/4365185)

One can use:

`settings.py`:

```
...
USER_AGENT_LIST = [
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',...,
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/48.0.2685.52'
]
...
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'chevaux_p_t.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
...
}
```

`middlewares.py`:

```
...
class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(settings.get('USER_AGENT_LIST'))
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)
            #One can do this to get the current user-agent used
            print("current user-agent:{}".format(request.headers[b'User-Agent']))
            logging.debug("current user-agent:{}".format(request.headers[b'User-Agent']))
```

Using this [solution](https://gist.github.com/bcambel/4365185) or not, one can make it appear in any method of your spider class as:

```
import logging
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    def a_method(self,response):
        print("current user-agent:{}".format(response.request.headers['User-Agent']))
        logging.debug("current user-agent:{}".format(response.request.headers['User-Agent']))
```

What changes is `response` added.